# Under which circumstances does Firebase Firestore database get downloaded?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an android app which uses Firebase Firestore database to store data. I store about 3600 questions and about 400 images. I know that firestore support offline. But I'm not sure whether the database download itself or not every time I request data from it. And under which circumstance does the firestore database get downloaded from the cloud? Does the database get only updated when the cloud database change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every query performed *while the app is online* will download all the necessary data from the database to satisfy that query.

Any data cached locally as a result of a prior query is only used when the app is offline.  As suggested by the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities), the idea is for your app to be usable when internet connectivity is interrupted.  The assumption is that the connectivity will eventually come back, and queries will revert to using the online database as the primary source of data.